# How to address objects loaded from glb file in Babylon JS game engine

Tags: javascript, blender, babylonjs

I am loading a  `.glb` file developed in Blender via the `BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh()` method.  One of the objects is called `Cube.003`.  However, after the method returns, `Cube.003` does not appear in the `scene.meshes` array.  It does appear in the scene, but not in the list.  How do I later address this object?  Thanks!

Comment: This video was useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D6BtdMnnQI

Answer (score 0):

To babylon.js you can refer to the names of the meshes loaded from `.glb`:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(null,"models/","example.glb", scene, function () {
cube = scene.getMeshByName("Cube.003");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28401433)